# adding task to non-default queue in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

I'm trying to add a task to non-default queue "slowQueue" using:

```
taskqueue.Queue('slowQueue').add(url='/worker/slow', params={'name': name})
```

I receive the error "TypeError: add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'url'"

How do you add a task to a non-default queue in google app engine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You suppose to add task(s) when calling Queue.add()

```
q = taskqueue.Queue('slowQueue') 
task = taskqueue.Task(url='/worker/slow', params={'name': name})
q.add(task)
```

Comment: Your response time is awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively (to Shay's answer), if you prefer a shorter but less object oriented style:

```
taskqueue.add(queue_name='slowQueue', url='/worker/slow', params={'name': name})
```